# Filter based on expression match

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I've been combing over regex related websites and tutorials to figure out how to accomplish this but unfortunately still can't get a clear grasp on regular expressions.  I have forum posts that have been tokenized and am trying to filter them based on posts that may have age related info.

For example, I used this snippet to try to filter:

```
re.search(r'.*(daughter|ds|son|dd|) (is|was|is turning|turned) ([0-9]{2})*', post)
```

This works on text such as the string

```
'my son was 7 when this incident occurred'
```

but also on the string

```
'is'
```

To filter,

```
r = re.compile('.*(daughter|ds|son|dd|)(is|was|is turning|turned)([0-9]{2}).*')
filter(r.match, ['my daughter is 7', 'is'])
```

but this returns an empty list when there should be a match with the first string.

What is wrong with the code snippet and what are some pointers to help with regular expression matches for my filtering?

Comment: How your regex would match `is` if the input string is exactly `is` ? https://regex101.com/r/oY2sI2/3

Comment: I dont think it matches `"is"` in fact it definitely doesn't (at least in python)

Comment: So you want to extract the age from the string or what?

Comment: I updated my post to reflect what I used to filter.  Right now, I just want to filter all the posts that contain that expression.

Comment: You have posted two expressions. To fix the first one add a `.` before the `*` in the end. To fix the second one add spaces like this: `'.*(daughter|ds|son|dd|) (is|was|is turning|turned) ([0-9]{2}).*'`. Also if you don't want to be limited to two digit ages you can go with something more realistic `[0-9]{1,3}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things to correct:

1 - In your regular expression:

```
.*(daughter|ds|son|dd|)(is|was|is turning|turned)([0-9]{2}).*
```

You are not taking into consideration the space characters between the words, so it will be:

```
.*(daughter|ds|son|dd|).*(is|was|is turning|turned).*([0-9]{2}).*
                       ^^                          ^^
```

2 - In the age group, you asking to only look for ages made of two numbers, so `7` will not match, thus you have to do it this way:

```
.*(daughter|ds|son|dd|).*(is|was|is turning|turned).*([0-9]{1,2}).*
                                                            ^
```

DEMO:

```
>>> r = re.compile('.*(daughter|ds|son|dd|).*(is|was|is turning|turned).*([0-9]{1,2}).*')
>>> l =filter(r.match, ['my daughter is 7', 'is'])
>>> 
>>> 
>>> l
['my daughter is 7']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first regex you posted:

```
'.*(daughter|ds|son|dd|) (is|was|is turning|turned) ([0-9]{2})*'
```

...it'll match anything greedily (including nothing because you have nothing after the last pipe in the first group) and hits the 'is'. It then looks for a space (between the ') (', and then because you have a '*' at the end, it catches 0-9 twice, zero or more times. This is why 'is' is catching.

Try this:

```
'.*(daughter|ds|son|dd)\s+(is|was|is turning|turned)\s+([0-9]{1,2}).*'
```